# how to check length inside each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i'm having trouble to check the `length` inside `$.each()` function

suppose i have 2 `elements` like this,

```html
<div class="demo">
    <!--  30 --   with different class>
   <input type="text" name="demo" class="hell"/>
   <input type="text" name="demo2" class="seeHere"/>
</div>
```

```js
$('.demo').find('input').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.find('.seeHere').length>0){  // throws error length of undifined
     // do something
   }else{
     // do something
   }
});
```

> it throws error length of undifined  for if
>
> as for the first time it will chache

```html
  <input type="text" name="demo"
         class="hell"/>
```

is there any way to return false inside `if(el.length>0 || return false)  like el.push(value || 'No value')`

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly you want to check in `if` statement? I guess you need to check `class` not the length there.

Comment: the code as shown (disregarding the lack of closing HTML comment) does not throw errors about `length of undefined` - you've removed too much real code or something ... and there is no `chache`ing going on

Comment: Your code should never throw the error mentioned, however `$this.find('.seeHere')` will always be a jquery object with length 0.

Comment: How do inputs have children? find() looks at children.... not the element you have selected.

Answer (score 2):

Use hasClass of jQuery

```
$('.demo').find('input').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
   if($this.hasClass('seeHere')){  
     // do something
   }else{
     // do something
  }
});
```

in jQuery's each function, $(this) resembles to the element of that selector at a index

What i mean to say is

Suppose you have something like this

```
<div id="#a" class="abc">
<div id="#b" class="abc">
<div id="#c" class="abc">
```

So when you loop through ".abc" like

```
$(".abc").each(function() {
      //Here $(this) resembles to $("#a") at first iteration
      // $("#b") at second iteration
      // $("#c") at third iteration
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate over anything - use the desired selector and the .length property to get the number of elements with that class..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var len = $('.seeHere').length;
  console.log(len);
//displays 2 in the console since there are two divs with the desired class
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="hell">
<div id="b" class="seeHere">
<div id="c" class="something">
<div id="d" class="seeHere">
```

and if you do want somethimg to happen to each element that has that class - use the .each() method on the selector:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.seeHere').each(function(){
      //do stuff
      });
    });
```